# Spark reading json number as string

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-java

I'm working on spark java application and using spark 2.4.7 version. I have a json file that I'm loading into dataframe like

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkSession().read().option("multiline",true).format(json).load(path_of_json);
```

The issue is that in my json file I have an attribute whose value is in number but when I printSchema() of the dataframe it is showing that attribute as StringType and not LongType.

Json file-

```
[
{"first": {
      "id" :"fdfd",
      "name":"temp",
      "type":-1       --> reading it as LongType
       },
 "something":"something_else",
 "data" : {
      "key": {
          "field":7569,   --> reading it as StringType
          "temp":"dfdfd"
       }
    }
}]
```

I tried reproducing the issue in my local spark shell but it is working fine there. Anyone has an idea why is it happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Spark tries to infer the schema automatically when reading from a Json file data source. However, if you know it, you can specify the schema when loading the Dataframe.

You first need to define the schema, an instance of the [`StructType`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/types/StructType.html) class, where you specify each field name and data type.
You can do it manually:

```java
StructType keyType = new StructType()
    .add(new StructField("field", DataTypes.LongType, true, Metadata.empty()))
    .add(new StructField("temp", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()));

StructType dataType = new StructType()
    .add(new StructField("key", keyType, true, Metadata.empty()));

StructType firstType = new StructType()
    .add(new StructField("id", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()))
    .add(new StructField("name", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()))
    .add(new StructField("type", DataTypes.LongType, true, Metadata.empty()));

StructType schema = new StructType()
    .add(new StructField("data", dataType, true, Metadata.empty()))
    .add(new StructField("first", firstType, true, Metadata.empty()))
    .add(new StructField("something", DataTypes.StringType, true, Metadata.empty()));
```

or from a DDL string:

```java
StructType schema = StructType.fromDDL("data STRUCT<key: STRUCT<field: BIGINT, temp: STRING>>,first STRUCT<id: STRING, name: STRING, type: BIGINT>,something STRING"));
```

Then specify the schema when loading the Dataframe:

```
Dataset<Row> df = spark.read()
        .option("multiline", true)
        .format("json")
        .schema(schema)
        .load(jsonPath);
```